# Request input from user in Telegram Bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I am really new to this (Python, telegram-bot), in fact, I just started learning this about 10 minutes ago. I have my bot running and I have done a lot of customization and response to defined keywords (e.g #paid).

I still want to extend the functionality of my bot, I am trying to implement a way of requesting input from a user. Sample scenario is below;

User sends: #paid

Bot replied: Enter Depositor Name:

User replied: John Doe

Bot Replied: Enter Teller No:

User replied: 129623

Bot replied: Depositor: John Doe, Teller No: 129623. If this information is correct, reply YES

User replied: YES

Bot replied: Thank you!

Then there will be a script to send the information via email.

Is this even possible?
I tried the following, when the User send `#paid`, nothing happens and there are no errors whatsoever.

**Code so far**

```
        if '#paid' in text:
               name = input("Enter Depositor's Name: ")
               teller = input("Enter Teller No: ")
               reply("Details;\n\n Name:" + name + "\nTeller No: " + str(teller) + "If the information is correct, enter YES")
               response = input("YES/NO: ")
          if 'YES' in response:
            reply("Thank You")
          else:
            reply('Try again')
        else:
            logging.info('error')
```

Comment: *"I just started learning this about 10 minutes ago"* - then you have definitely not yet done enough research of your own.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Because I said 10 minutes? Do I need to spend a year first to justify that I did my research and I am stuck? Is that even logical?

Comment: Not a year, but definitely more than ten minutes - see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3001761

Comment: Which I did, If I did not, I couldn't I gotten to the stage I am now stuck.